# How to serve static files from nginx subfolders

Tags: nginx, download, sendfile

I am trying to send files from from subdirectories from the nginx server.
When the URL is *http://localhost:8080/media/photo.jpg* the Nginx sends the file from the path

> /Users/utsavdusad/Desktop/Pilot_App_test/uploads

It doesn't send the file from the subfolders in *uploads* directory.

```
location  /media  {
        sendfile on;
        alias /Users/utsavdusad/Desktop/Pilot_App_test/uploads;
        autoindex on;

    }
```

I want to serve the files from a subdirectory of the uploads folder. for e.g.: **../uploads/photos**

Comment: Where do you want `/media/photo.jpg` served from?

Comment: Do you prevent access by file types or you want to allow all files and prevent listing of all subdirectories?

Comment: I want to allow the files from all subdirectories of **uploads** folder.

Comment: It does. Check error_log. Or may be you have other locations overriding this one.